# How do I correcty reshape my data in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been trying to make the CNN in the Tensorflow CNN tutorial work with 3D Data. But I always get this one dimension error. I apologize in advance, because this is my first time asking a question on stackoverflow so this might look a little bit messy. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

IMG_SIZE_PX = 50
SLICE_COUNT = 20
n_classes = 2
keep_rate = 0.8
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

def neural_network(features, labels, mode):

    input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"],shape = [-1,IMG_SIZE_PX, IMG_SIZE_PX, SLICE_COUNT, 1])

    conv1 = tf.layers.conv3d(inputs = input_layer, filters = 32, kernel_size = [1,2,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,2,1], 
                         padding = "same", activation = tf.nn.relu)

    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling3d(inputs = conv1, pool_size = [1,2,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,2,1], padding = "same")

    conv2 = tf.layers.conv3d(inputs = pool1, filters = 64, kernel_size = [1,2,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,2,1], 
                         padding = "same", activation = tf.nn.relu)

    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling3d(inputs = conv2, pool_size = [1,2,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,2,1], padding = "same")

    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 50000])
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs = pool2_flat, units = 1024, activation = tf.nn.relu)

    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs = dense, rate = 0.4, training = mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs = dropout, units = 2)
    predictions = {
        "classes" : tf.argmax(input = logits, axis = 1),
        "probabilities" : tf.nn.softmax(logits, name = "softmax_tensor")
    }
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode = mode, predictions = predictions)

    onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices = tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth = 2)
    loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels = onehot_labels, logits = logits)


    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.001)
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss = loss, global_step = tf.train.get_global_step())
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode = mode, loss = loss, train_op = train_op)

    eval_metric_ops = {"accuracy" : tf.metrics.accuracy(labels = labels, predictions = predictions["classes"])}
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode = mode, loss = loss, eval_metric_ops = eval_metric_ops)

#main

def main(unused_argv):

    training_data = train_data[0]
    training_labels = train_data[1]
    eval_data = train_data[0]
    eval_labels = train_data[1]

    lung_classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = neural_network, 
                                     model_dir = "SOME_DIR")

    tensors_to_log = {"probabilities" : "softmax_tensor"}
    logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors = tensors_to_log, every_n_iter = 50)

    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x = {"x" : np.array(training_data)},
        y = np.array(training_labels),
        batch_size = 50,
        num_epochs = None,
        shuffle = True)
    lung_classifier.train(input_fn = train_input_fn, steps = 20000, hooks = [logging_hook])

    eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x = {"x" : eval_data},
        y = eval_labels,
        num_epochs = 1,
        shuffle = false)
    eval_results = lung_classifier.evaluate(input_fn = eval_input_fn)
    print(eval_results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
        tf.app.run()
```

I get this Error Message:

```
ValueError: Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 50000 but is 50 for
'Reshape' (op: 'Reshape') with input shapes: [50], [5] and with input
tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [?,50,50,20,1].
```

The Error message is pretty long so I simply show you the origin of it.

```
input_layer = tf.reshape(features["x"],shape = [-1,IMG_SIZE_PX, IMG_SIZE_PX, SLICE_COUNT, 1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your features["x"] has dimensions 50x5 and you are trying to give it a dimension of batch_size x 50 x 50 x 20 x 1 which is not possible.

Ensure that you are reading your data correctly by printing out its shape.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I made the wrong shape during the Preprocessing. Which led to this error in the network.